# raml2html not generating arrays declarations properly

Tags: raml

I am using the raml2html tool to generate html documentation for my ReST apis.

I have defined all my types in a raml file `memberTypes.raml` that I include in the main `service.raml`.

Following is a sample from the `service.raml` file.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: update member object
uses:
  memberTypes: /memberTypes.raml

types:
  Member:
    properties:
      termsAndConditions:
        type: memberTypes.TermsAndConditions[]
        description: The terms and conditions that the member has accepted.
        required: false
      person:
        type: memberTypes.Person
        description: The personal details of the member.
        required: true
```

And following is a sample for the 2 properties above in `memberTypes.raml`

```
  Person:
    properties:
      personName:
        type: NameType
        description: The name of the member.
        required: true
      dateOfBirth:
        type: DateOfBirth
        required: true
  TermsAndConditions:
    properties:
      version:
        type: string
        description: The version of the terms and conditions.
      acceptedDate:
        type: date-only
        description: The date on which the corresponding terms and conditions were accepted. Format is YYYY-MM-DD, ISO-8601 Calendar date format.
```

Now, below is the what I get in the html

[image]

The array is shown as `array of memberTypes.TermsAndConditions`. 
The questions is how do i get rid of the `memberTypes`? i simply want the type to be
 `array of TermsAndConditions`.
How do I achieve this? is there a command line option to raml2html tool that will do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is command line option to do that, since the template / theme of raml2html defines how things are shown in HTML. You can edit the default theme. If I recall correctly that is defined in `item.nunjucks` file.

The usual use case for that is "array of objects" or "array of strings" but there is also definitions how to show non standard type types.